# How to go about repairing a ripped solder pad on a USB flash drive?

Tags: pcb, usb-device, repair, pad

I have a flash drive that sustained damage to the USB port. It looked like it just needed to be reseated with fresh solder and some TLC so I went ahead and started to remove the damaged port, then one of the data line pads (the one on the left) came up with the rest of the port as it looks to have been damaged along withy the port itself. What is the best way to proceed?

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like one of the data lines (which are the inner two contacts); that's Vcc, no? Given that it's just a power supply line, wiring into another point on the board (that's normally connected via traces anyway) shouldn't impact performance at all (the data lines are picky about impedance and trying to repair them might prevent use of any high-speed modes the drive supports, but the power lines aren't).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a new connector and not a wire dangling about, I would:

1. take a 15 mm length of thin wire (from an USB or ehternet cable or such)
2. Strip ends of the cable and pre-tin them
3. solder one end on the lower end of the resistor that has "2R2" on it
4. solder the USB connector in
5. bend the wire to the unconnected pin and solder it. Don't hold the soldering iron on the connector pad/pin for too long, or the plastics will be affected and might cause a poor connection.

Soldering flux on all surfaces that are soldered often helps in getting the solder flow properly. Though, flux shouldn't be put in the inside of the connector where it mates to the cable connector.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to:

- Very thoroughly clean all flux from the board.  Must be clean and dry of all chemicals, including solvents.
- Gently clean and flatten the pad if needed.
- Apply a tiny amount of gel superglue or epoxy to the pad and trace PCB location - don't want it oozing everywhere.
- Squish the pad down gently and slowly, maintaining alignment and flatness; avoid squishing until nothing else oozes - this causes the pad to bend and it'll void underneath.
- Scrape up any oozed excess before it hardens.
- Leave to cure for at least 12h, no exceptions, preferably with gentle airflow.
- Scrape the ends of the broken trace to expose copper, ends should be touching.
- Flux it, get a tiny ball of solder on the iron, and touch it - should connect.  If in doubt, check it with a magnifier and/or multimeter.
- Install the USB-A connector and solder as usual, except for the repaired pad.  Flux that one and repeat like the broken trace - the less time it stays hot, the better.  Aim for a functional joint, not a pretty one.
- Even the best repair is not as robust as the original fab. Get your data, then consider it a "last resort" unit (not a daily driver.)